# Option value syntax for help message in python argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to get params like `--set=X=Y` with argparse, python. A first approach is:

```
parser.add_argument('--set', dest='d', metavar='book=from:to', action='append', type=str, required=True, help='...')
```

I'd have to split the result (`X=Y`) myself, but that's okay.
My question regards the syntax of the generated help message (`--help`) from argparse. It's using the probably more common syntax `--set X=Y` what results in:

```
--set book=from:to  ...
```

Is there a way for me to change this behavior so the help looks like:

```
--set=book=from:to  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not without creating your own custom sub-class of the `argparse.HelpFormatter()` class.

This would require replacing internal, private methods of that class. The current implementation uses this method:

```
def _format_action_invocation(self, action):
    if not action.option_strings:
        metavar, = self._metavar_formatter(action, action.dest)(1)
        return metavar

    else:
        parts = []

        # if the Optional doesn't take a value, format is:
        #    -s, --long
        if action.nargs == 0:
            parts.extend(action.option_strings)

        # if the Optional takes a value, format is:
        #    -s ARGS, --long ARGS
        else:
            default = action.dest.upper()
            args_string = self._format_args(action, default)
            for option_string in action.option_strings:
                parts.append('%s %s' % (option_string, args_string))

        return ', '.join(parts)
```

Note the `parts.append('%s %s' % (option_string, args_string))`; you'd have to provide your own version of the above method with the space replaced with an `=` equals sign.

The problem with doing this is that a future version of the `argparse` library would be perfectly within it's rights to use a *different* method name, breaking your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid most of the problem of the 'future compliance' of the above solution, another approach is to decorate the `_format_action_invocation` instead. It wouldn't break if the `argparse` method changes its name of course, but at least it allows for `argparse` code updates within the method and avoids code duplication.

As a bonus, the below solution allows also to change the helper in the usage line, to keep consistency between usage and invocation sections:

```
import re

def deco_argparse_format_action(func, is_invoc=False):
    def wrapper_format_action(*args, **kwargs):
        '''
        Replaces `-f FOO' or  '--foo FOO` by resp. `-f=FOO` and `--foo=FOO` in argparse helper.
        Although there is always possibility to use either `--foo FOO` or
        `--foo=FOO`, it is sometimes better to document the '=' way
        rather than the ' ' way.
        For example, when the option argument contains special characters like '-'
        it must be expressed with '=' in order to not confuse the shell that executes
        the command line.
        '''
        string = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if is_invoc is True:
            # 'invocation section' case
            patt = r"(-+[^ ,]+) +"
            repl = r"\1="
        else:
            # 'usage section' case
            patt = r"(\[-+[^ \]]+) +([^|])"
            repl = r"\1=\2"

        return re.sub(patt,repl,string)
    return wrapper_format_action
```

Usage:

```
import argparse

#-- Customize helper for options with arguments
#   (print '-f=FOO, --foo=FOO' instead of '-f FOO, --foo FOO')
HelpFormatter._format_action_invocation = deco_argparse_format_action(
        HelpFormatter._format_action_invocation,
        is_invoc = True,
        )

HelpFormatter._format_actions_usage = deco_argparse_format_action(
        HelpFormatter._format_actions_usage,
        )
```